# Extracting a tag value in BeautifulSoup when unable to match by position or attributes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BS to scrape a web page and i'm a little stuck with a small problem. Here's a snippet of HTML from the page.

```
<span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Artist:</span> M.I.A.<br>
</span>
```

Once I've got the soup, how can I find this tag and get the artist name i.e. M.I.A.
I cannot match the tag with the `style` attribute as it is used in a dozen places in the page. I don't even know the exact location of the `span` tag as it changes position from page to page. Therefore, I can't match by position. The artist name changes but the title span structure is always the same.

I would only like the extract the artist name (the M.I.A. bit).

Comment: So you want stuff after a tag with the text value of "Artist:"?   Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`BeautifulSoup` is kind of dead, since `SGMLParser` is deprecated. I suggest you use the better `lxml` library -- It even has [**xpath**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) support!!

```
from lxml import html

text = '''
<span style="font-family: arial;">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">Artist:</span>M.I.A.<br>
</span>
'''

doc = html.fromstring(text)
print ''.join(doc.xpath("//span/span[text()='Artist:']/../text()"))
```

This xpath expression means *"find the `span` tag which is inside another `span` tag and contains the text `'Artist:'`, and grab all the text of the parent containing tag"*. It correctly prints `M.I.A.` as one would expect.